# How to disable programmatically created UIBarButtonItem in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, toolbar, uibarbuttonitem

I create a toolbar programmatically and add four UIBarButtonItem also programmatically in the toolbar. 
This button will appear when text view begin editing, if no text in textview clear button and translate button will disable. 
Here is my four button creating code.

```
UIToolbar* numberToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
numberToolbar.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

numberToolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hide" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(cancelKeyboard)],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Clear" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(clearTextView)],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Paste" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(paste)],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil],
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Translate" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(translate)],
                       nil];
[numberToolbar sizeToFit];
_sorceTextview.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar;
_sorceTextview.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
```

now how can i disable clear and translate button in:

```
-(BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {}
```

method? plz help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use instance variables for those buttons. Then you can set the `enabled` property as needed.

```
@implementation MyViewController {
    UIBarButtonItem *_btnClear;
    UIBarButtonItem *_btnTranslate;
}
```

Then in your toolbar setup code:

```
_btnClear = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Clear" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(clearTextView)];
_btnTranslate = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Translate" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(translate)];
UIBarButtonItem *flex = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

numberToolbar.items = @[
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hide" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(cancelKeyboard)],
                       flex,
                       _btnClear,
                       flex,
                       [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Paste" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(paste)],
                       flex,
                       _btnTranslate
                       ];
```

Then wherever you need to disable you can do:

```
_btnClear.enabled = NO;
```

and to enable:

```
_btnClear.enabled = YES;
```

Comment: tq.. i also thinking like this. Thank you very much. @rmaddy

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept answers that solve your issues.

Comment: Brother, i need another thing. if nothing have to be paste of my phone memory then paste button also disable. how to understand UIPasteBoard have something or empty? @rmaddy

Comment: That's a completely different question. I suggest you do some searching on the topic first. Then post a new question if you are still stuck.